# Xampp port not working

Tags: xampp, port-forwarding

I've got xampp installed on ubuntu. The port which I'm using is 3000.
Let's say that my IP address is 123.123.123.123

When from another device I'm checking port 3000 for page 123.123.123.123 it's saying it is open.

When I'm opening page 123.123.123.123:3000 on my computer it's working.
However when I'm opening 123.123.123.123:3000 on another device it's not working.

How is it possible? (The port is open)

*it looks like client is being redirected to localhost.

Answer (score 0):

It's a security measure by Xampp.
In the end of `xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-xampp.conf` you can find the following code:

```
<LocationMatch "^/(?i:(?:xampp|security|licenses|phpmyadmin|webalizer|server-status|server-info))">
    Require local
    ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</LocationMatch>
```

Edit it adding you lan prefix, for example:

```
<LocationMatch "^/(?i:(?:xampp|security|licenses|phpmyadmin|webalizer|server-status|server-info))">
    Require local
    Require ip 192.168
    ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</LocationMatch>
```

Comment: I add that line, but it's still not working.

Comment: Did you add your actual lan prefix? I wrote 192.168 because that's mine, yours may be different. Is the device you're trying to connect to your site under the same lan?

Comment: yes, I wrote my own

Comment: Are you writing :3000 after ip address on th second device?

Comment: yes, I'am writing it

Comment: I'm sorry I really don't know what's the problem, maybe permissions on files. I'd try checking permissions, creating a virtual host and then editing hosts file on the second device, but I don't know if this could solve the issue.